# Question about java IO FileInputStream written by myself

Tags: java, java-io

I wrote an example of FileInputStream,But I found that if I use read() directly in the loop, there will be a problem with the printed data, and it cannot be displayed completely. After using the int variable to receive the return value of read(), it can be displayed normally here. Why?
code:

```java
    String path = "d:/hello.txt";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    int readData = 0;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        while ((readData = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) readData);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to both test and print the return value of `read()`, so you need a variable.

Comment: Note that the read method is reading a byte, not a char, see the JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-- And note that a byte is not a char, the main difference between is that byte is used to store raw binary data but a char is used to store character data